# Using Javascript & Google Calendar API v3, how do I allow the user to specify a non-primary calendar to add an event?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'm a beginner when it comes to the Google Calendar API and still a beginner with javascript. I'm trying to allow my users to add an event to a calendar of their choosing. I can authenticate using Oauth2 and can set it up so they can add the event to a calendar with a hard-coded calendar id but I can't figure out how to allow them to choose a calendar. I've perused the web but have come up with nothing. Any help is much appreciated.
CRS

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done. Again, I'm just learning javascript, but the following function lets me get a list of calendars with the calendarID and calendarSummary. I use these values to create links that pass the calendarID variable to a page that will be handled by the server.  That page passes the URL variable to a javascript function that inserts the event using the calendarID.

```
function getAvailableCalendars() {
      gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list();
        request.execute(function(resp) {
            var mydiv = document.createElement('div');
            mydiv.innerHTML = 'Choose a calendar to insert the event:<br />'
          for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
            var calendarID = resp.items[i].id;
            var calendarSummary = resp.items[i].summary;
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.title = calendarSummary;
            a.innerHTML += a.title + '<br />';
            a.href='http://mysite.com/intakeCalInsert.cfm?calendar=' +calendarID;
            mydiv.appendChild(a);
            document.getElementById('events').appendChild(mydiv);

          }
        });
      });
    }
```

I'm sure this could be handled much more efficiently but it works for me. Maybe someone can get some ideas from this code and make it much better.